# Embedding the value from one cell within text in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's an image of what I want to accomplish.

[image: Sample]

The "function" is shown as pseudo-code in column E, and the desired result in column F.  I want to include the values from columns B and D within the text in column F.  How would I do that?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Your question is not clear now, please EDIT it to make better. "field" word is used for forms, for the picture you attached proper name is "cell". Do you have the input in column E and want to generate column F? Are you happy with a solution using formulas, or do you definitely need a macro? Please share what have you tried so far, we aren't a free code writing service.

Answer (score 4):

You actually don't need anything fancy.  You can concatenate text and values with an ampersand.  So, for example, `F2` would be:

```
="This item for sale is "&B2&", item number "&D2
```

Comment: Perfect. I was hoping it was something simple. Thanks!